# How to contribute to Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In this [blog](https://techcrunch.com/2019/05/07/google-launches-jetpack-compose-an-open-source-kotlin-based-ui-development-toolkit/), Tech Crunch says,

> Google launches Jetpack Compose, an open-source, Kotlin-based UI development toolkit

This means JetPack Compose is an open-source framework (obviously). Then... where's the source code for Jetpack Compose? And how can someone contribute to it?

I searched for the same on the internet but found nothing. Any leads would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out this [contributing guide](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/CONTRIBUTING.md) and here's the compose source code: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/compose.
Note that not all libraries from Android are open for outside contribution AFAIK, but you can definitely contribute to the Compose compiler.

[Yigit](https://twitter.com/yigitboyar) recently answered a related question on I/O 21. As a summary: they plan on opening up libraries so that everyone can contribute, but it has an effect on their regular development processes.

Also, here is the androidx github repo: https://github.com/androidx/androidx

Comment: I would say that, at least for the runtime of Compose, even if it is not specifically listed, start with a PR in GitHub. If the change is one we want to take we will help do the work necessary to convert it to a change in AOSP and help you set up the AOSP development environment if necessary.